# What does $find('mycontrol') do that jquery $('#mycontrol') doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does `$find('mycontrol')` do that jquery's `$('#mycontrol')` doesn't?

How are they different?
Sorry, I'm a JS novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is invalid unless you defined a function named `$find`, and the selector is missing its `#` if the [`id-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)  is intended.

If you mean:

```
$('.someSelector').find('#mycontrol')
```

vs

```
$('#mycontrol')
```

Then:

- the first searches from within the context of the elements matched by `$('.someSelector')`
- the second searches the entire document.

Because you're trying to get an element by ID, you might as well use the second version because there can only be one on the page anyway (IDs must be unique), and selecting by ID is generally very fast.

If `#mycontrol` should only be fetched if it happens to descend from some other selector, you could use the second version, but this would be a rare case I would think.

Comment: Yes but in the case of looking for something by "id" value, it really doesn't matter.  (I don't think that "find" makes sure that the found element(s) are really children of one of the starting point elements, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: Worth noting the second argument in $ (jQuery) function is the context as well.  Using find is the equivalent of:  $('.someSelector', '#mycontrol');

Comment: @Pointy: I'm pretty sure it does. Let me put together a quick test... EDIT: Yep, looks like the context is enforced even though we're searching for an ID. http://jsfiddle.net/Dzysv/

Comment: @Jake: True, but I personally don't like that form. It's a little slower, and less readable in my opinion, though it is a little more concise.